# mongoDB: Can't add an field to an array object

Tags: javascript, mongodb

This is how my db document looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : "aN2jGuR2rSzDx87LB",
    "content" : {
        "en" : [
            {
                "content" : "Item 1",
                "timestamp" : 1518811796
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now I need to add another field in the first object of the `content.en` array.
The document itself gets selected by an ID.
The result should be:

```
{
  "_id" : "aN2jGuR2rSzDx87LB",
  "content" : {
    "en" : [
      {
        "content" : "Item 1",
        "timestamp" : 1518811796,
        "user" : {
          "id" : 'userId'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried to do it like this, but nothing is happening. I don't even get an error message.

```
Content.update(
  { _id: id },
  {
    $addToSet: {
      'content.en.0.user': {
        id: 'userId',
      }
    }
  }
)
```

Also I would like to use an variable for the language. How do I do that? Something like `'content.' + language + '.0.user'`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) is useful when you want to add someting to an array. In your case you want to modify first element of your array (at index `0`) so you should simply use [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)  (which is field update operator):

```
Content.update(
   { _id: "aN2jGuR2rSzDx87LB" },
   {
      $set: {
         "content.en.0.user": {
         id: "userId",
      }
   }
 }
)
```